# Desktop-like jsf-web-application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to create a desktop-like application with JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 2.2.1
I created a main Layout with two divs, the upper div containing a menubar with several submenus. When the user chooses a menuitem, I want to show the spezifyed xhtml page in the bottom div of my main layout, without loading the full page. So I am thinking of Ajax to do it. But I don't know how to realize it.

And by the way, is there a chance to change a p:menubar or a p:submenu by javascript?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you see [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/macosx.jsf)? Maybe you will find some hints in the source. Otherwise a piece of source code would help to see how far you did it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had a look at the example. But this example just uses dialogs to show on the "Mac-Screen". I am looking for a method, showing a facelet in a div, and replacing it with another facelet, without reloading the complete page. At this time, I have nearly no code, because I just start thinking about this.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of being down-voted, may I suggest that since it sounds like you're at the beginning of your project, you should consider a framework other than JSF 2.0 because it sounds like you're shoe-horning. GWT is the most obvious candidate. If you're used to desktop app development (especially in Java), Vaadin is another great candidate.

Comment: No, GWT is definitely not an option. I do GWT at work, and I hate it. Sorry, but this is only my opinion. What I've seen so far from JSF, I like it. But I don't understand exactly the phases.

Comment: If you have your heart set on it, then I can only recommend you buy either Core JavaServer Faces 3rd edition and/or JavaServer Faces 2.0: The Complete Reference. But I can tell you now you're signing yourself up for a world of pain.